# Detached entity occurs when the EntityManager is RequestScoped and the bean is ViewScoped

Tags: jsf, jpa, jsf-2, cdi

I am doing a simple CRUD, using JSF, JPA and CDI.

The EntityManager of my DAO is produced as RequestScoped and I have a ViewScoped bean, in the second request of this bean when I save the object the exception happens: "detached entity passed to persist".

What is the best way to make sure that the EntityManager will close, but not have problem with detached object and lazy initialization?

---

```
@Produces
@RequestScoped
public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
    return factory.createEntityManager();
}
public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
    manager.close();
}
```

Comment: By either re-attaching the entities (merging) or using an extended persistence manager. Do some searching on the internet. Lots of info to be found.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you for the comment, merge really works, I was using persist. About the "extended persistence manager", the tutorials that I found presupposes that I know EJB3 and its peculiarities. I have to study more!

Comment: Keep in mind though that with merging   you could overwrite the same entity if it was already retrieved and manipulated in the same session but in a different object!!!

Comment: That exception has got nothing to do with closing the `EntityManager`. It is thrown, when inconsistency in maintaining a bidirectional relationship is involved. `EntityManager#persist()` works only with a transient instance (created using `new`). If an auto-generated field in an entity is set manually after it has been created using `new` or an entity is supplied from a non-transactional context, it is considered to be a detached entity. That exception occurs, when such entity is attempted to be passed to persist.

Comment: Good reading: http://blog.xebia.com/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/